# Подмена контентов в iframe

Tags: php

Необходимо менять результаты в зависимости от выбора chekbox/option, и привязать эти действия к кнопке.Проблема в том,что кнопка никак не реагирует на атрибут onclick = "****.php".В общем вот код:

```
<div class="logic">
  <form action="main.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="pdf" value="pdf"><a>pdf</a>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="djvu"><a>djvu</a>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="fb2"><a>fb2</a>
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="anything"><a>Любой формат</a>
    <br>
    <a>Сортировать: </a>
    <br>
    <select name="sorting">
      <option disabled selected value="Выберите сортировку">Выберите сортировку</option>
      <option value="decrease_sort" id="decrease_sort">Сортировка по убыванию</option>
      <option value="increase_sort">Сортировка по возрастанию</option>
      <option value="authors_sort">Сортировка по авторам</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Подтвердить" name="confirmButton" class="button button1">
    <input class="button button2" type="reset" value="Сбросить" name="Сбросить">
  </form>
</div>

<iframe src="main.php" width="50%" height="100%" class="frame"></iframe>
```

---

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
mysqli_set_charset($link,'utf-8');
if(!($link)){
    die('error of connection' .mysql_error());
}
if(isset($_POST['increase_sort'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM издательство ORDER BY Год_издания ASC";
    $result  = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $i['Наименование']. "-\t </br> <b>Год:</b> \t";
        echo $i['Год_издания']. ", \t <b>Страниц:</b> \t "; 
        echo $i['Количество_страниц']. " </br>"; 
    }
}else if(isset($_POST['decrease_sort'])){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM издательство ORDER BY Год_издания DESC";
    $result  = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $i['Наименование']. "-\t </br> <b>Год:</b> \t";
        echo $i['Год_издания']. ", \t <b>Страниц:</b> \t "; 
        echo $i['Количество_страниц']. " </br>"; 
    }
}else{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM издательство";
    $result  = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $i['Наименование']. "-\t </br> <b>Год:</b> \t";
        echo $i['Год_издания']. ", \t <b>Страниц:</b> \t "; 
        echo $i['Количество_страниц']. " </br></br>"; 
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Тег `<br>` — одиночный тег: его закрывать не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="button" value="Подтвердить"  name="confirmButton" class="button button1">
```

Заменить  на:

```
<input type="submit" value="Подтвердить"  name="confirmButton" class="button button1">
```

Потом

```
<form action="main.php" method="post">
```

Заменить на:

`<form action="main.php" method="post" target="fc_iframe">`

и

`<iframe src="main.php" width="50%" height="100%" class="frame" ></iframe>` 
на `<iframe name="fc_iframe" src="main.php" width="50%" height="100%" class="frame" ></iframe>`

Comment: Загружается отдельная страница .php.Как привязать к iframe ?

Comment: <form action="main.php" method="post"> 
Заменить на: <form action="main.php" method="post"  target="fc_iframe"> 

и 

<iframe src="main.php" width="50%" height="100%"
    class="frame" ></iframe> 
на
<iframe name="fc_iframe" src="main.php" width="50%" height="100%"
    class="frame" ></iframe>